# Is the [web-api] tag useful?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) does not add anything useful to a questoin.

It is usually used to mean:

- I am using an API - These should be tagged with the specific API or platform
- Which API can I use to do X - These are off topic and should be closed

I think [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) should be burninated.

Comment: I swear my oath to only one nation. Burnination!

Comment: I too am in [agreement](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNBK.jpg).

Comment: Hmm, Web API has at least three different meanings: A Microsoft API in ASP.NET MVC, a platform or standard that [Mozilla is building](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI), and as a general term for any API connected to the Web.

Comment: I already had [tag:webapi] on my list-of-57, but the hyphenated form snuck through.  A *lot* of those questions (the majority by far) are about the ASP.MVC Web API bits and can be safely retagged.  The rest... *burn*.